# Запустить независимый скрипт Python из другого скрипта

Tags: python

Мне нужно из одного скрипта **Python** запустить несколько других, которые находятся в разных директориях, причём так, чтобы когда этот скрипт завершал свою работу, остальные продолжали.

Я пробовал и `os.system("python /.../")` и `subprocess.Popen()` но при завершении этого процесса, скрипты останавливались.

Answer (score 3):

`os.system()` вызывает shell команду и ждёт пока завершится -- родитель не выйдет, пока shell работает.

`subprocess.Popen()` не запускает shell и не ждёт пока дочерний процесс завершится. Родитель может выйти, пока запущенный процесс ещё работает. Демонстрация:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import Popen
import sys

print('готовимся запустить процесс')
Popen([sys.executable, '-c', 'import time; time.sleep(3); print("дитё")'])
print('выходим')
```

Если вы запустите это с командной строчки, то результат:

```
independent-process » python3 .                                      
готовимся запустить процесс
выходим
independent-process » дитё
```

Здесь `»` это приглашение для ввода в shell. Видно, что родитель печатает и выходит, что сигнализируется выводом приглашения к новой команде `»`. А дочерний процесс всё ещё продолжает работать и позже свой вывод добавляет.

На Unix, слова "независимый скрипт" могут имеют градации: начиная с `&` (выполнять асинхронно) в bash (как `Popen()` в Питоне), nohup (перенаправить ввод/вывод, игнорировать HUP сигнал, генерируемый при выходе из терминала), setsid (свою [сессию (группы процессов) завести](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6548823/4279), чтобы например, продолжать работать после <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>, которое генерирует SIGINT для процессов, в запущенной задаче, представленной активной группой процессов), до systemd/[supervisord](http://supervisord.org/introduction.html)/etc сервисов ([демоны](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing))).