# Выполять код в фоновом режиме

Tags: python

Этот кусок когда выполняется бесконечно. Можно ли выполнять его в фоне, чтобы выполнялся код после него? Если да, то подскажите как это сделать

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key,Listener
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename=("log.txt"),level=logging.DEBUG,format='% 
(message)s')
def on_press(key):logging.info(key)
with Listener(on_press=on_press)as listener:listener.join()
```

Comment: `nohup /path/to/test.py &` попробуйте

Comment: связанный вопрос [Запустить независимый скрипт Python из другого скрипта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/693446/23044)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замени строку

`with Listener(on_press=on_press)as listener:listener.join()`

на

`listener = Listener(on_press=on_press)
listener.start()`

Обертка `with ... as ... :` делает сама этот start() перед тем как выполнить первую команду после ":".

join() будет ждать завершения работы Listener. В твоём коде он там и повисает.

P.S. Советую придерживаться [PEP8](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html#id2).

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло