# Запуск и контроль процессов из скрипта

Tags: python, subprocess

Мне нужно создать программу, которая по команде запускает процесс(telegram-cli) и в дальнейшем отслеживает его состояние. При этом, при запуске процесс может запросить телефон и пароль, которые моя программа должна ввести. Вот как это выглядит(FreeBSD): [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно, что я пробовал: запускать клиент телеграмма как subprocess.Popen:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["telegram-cli", "--json", "-p", profile, "-P", str(port)],
                                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                       stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

    while True:
       line = process.stdout.readline()
       print(line)
```

Во-первых, если так делать - считывающий поток зависает пока не будет введена строка в stdout, но даже если опустить это - "phone number: " - не строка, и считать это не получится.

В общем, мне кажется, что я иду не по тому пути, и прошу намекнуть, какие технологии я могу использовать для решения задачи.

Comment: вот [пример кода как передать две строки в дочернюю команду и прочитать её вывод (через pipe или pty)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22470728/4279)

Comment: у меня получилось запустить процесс и ввести данные с помощью pexpect. Изучу этот инструмент получше, большое спасибо!

Comment: Я так и не смог найти возможности после запуска и передачи данных процессу, просто оставить его работать, не блокируя текущий поток

Comment: `process = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE); process.stdin.write(b'some input'); process.stdin.flush()` всё

Comment: В зависимости насколько независимым вы хотите процесс сделать, возможно  ещё нужны шаги: [Запустить независимый скрипт Python из другого скрипта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/693446/23044)

Comment: я ведь указал - изначально пытался использовать pexpect вместо Popen. Но таки сейчас вернулся к subprocess.Popen, так как нашел статью человека, который смог читать Pipe без блокировки(без чего я и не мог использовать Popen):
http://eyalarubas.com/python-subproc-nonblock.html
Спасибо за помощь, надеюсь, подводные камни на этом закончились :)

Comment: вы сказали "просто оставить работать", а на самом деле вы хотите ещё вывод читать? Не блокируя основной поток? [Non-blocking read on a subprocess.PIPE in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/375427/4279)

Comment: касательно, именно telegram-cli — посмотрите даёт ли команда возможность через socket с ней общаться (то есть cli запускает сервер, а вы ей запросы шлёте по мере необходимости).